# source URI is not allowed in this document

Tags: browser, http-headers

I am working on a website on my `localhost` and suddenly I'm now getting this errors.

I get this error on Firefox

```
<script> source URI is not allowed in this document
```

And nothing on chrome,` but if I try using the files code, I get:

```
Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.
```

It is basically for: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js.

The browser doesn't even send a GET request for the file.

Everything used to work perfect before. Not sure why I'm getting this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had an extension installed on both of my browsers. It was preventing it from loading.

If you have any VPNs, hide-tracking extensions, then it needs to be disabled.

In my case it was **Disconnect** firefox/chrome extension.

Comment: u saved my sanity! :)
the crazy thing is that this issue just started out of the blue after everything worked for more then a week

Comment: A possible cause that has arisen after this answer (I think) is Firefox tracking protection. Try disabling that to resolve this too.

Comment: In my case it was Ghostery firefox addon. Disabling it solves the problem for me.

Comment: Mine is uBlock extension

Comment: Not an extension here. I do load a local script file from a local html file in the same folder though, maybe that's it?