# Firefox refuses to load firebase auth script

Tags: firebase, firefox, firebase-authentication, content-security-policy

When trying to use Firebase Authentication with Google, the error `auth/internal` occurs and the following warning appears in the console:

`<script> source URI is not allowed in this document: “https://apis.google.com/js/api.js”`

This only happens in Firefox. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has a different policy for how network requests are treated within your script.
Firefox requests occur only within the context of the extension.
You need to declare which sites you are making requests to
You will have to place these within
`manifest.json`
in the permissions key

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555424/source-uri-is-not-allowed-in-this-document/50556568